# Add repeating XML code n times via xslt template

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to repeat the following lines in an XML document n times, n being set in the variable $n

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
    <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[i]</Data>
</Cell>
```

and rather than writing clumsy cascades like

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[0]</Data>
</Cell>
<xsl:if test="$n &gt; 1>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
    <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[1]</Data>
  </Cell>
    <xsl:if test="$n &gt; 2>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
        <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[2]</Data>
      </Cell>
    .
    .
    .
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
```

I'd like to solve this with an elegant template, but I have no idea how to iteratively glue XML and text strings together to get something like this:

n=3

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
    <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[0]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
    <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[1]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
    <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[2]</Data>
</Cell>
```

---

I have applied Daniel's code to my XSLT with this template

```
<xsl:template name="repeater">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="n"/>
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
        concat(substring-before($string,'['),
        '[',$count,']',
        substring-after($string,']')))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n - 1 > $count">
      <xsl:call-template name="copyXML">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count+1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and with the following call

```
<xsl:call-template name="repeater">
  <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$nAllergens"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="string">
    <![CDATA[
      <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[i]</Data></Cell>
    ]]>
  </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

$nAllergens being 3, I get back

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[0]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[1]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[2]</Data>
</Cell>
```

That's good.
But what if I want to get

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[0]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[0]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[1]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[1]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[2]</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
  <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[2]</Data>
</Cell>
```

?

I have 
a) added a second  line to my template 
b) changed the concat-call to
    concat(substring-before($string,'['),
            '[',$count,']',substring-after($string,']'),
           substring-before($string,'['),
            '[',$count,']',substring-after($string,']'))

Both ways I only get
    
      WSCEAllergens[0]
    
    
      WSCEAllergens[0]
    
    
      WSCEAllergens[1]
    
    
      WSCEAllergens[2]

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: Your new requirement is not clear. What are the input parameters here? Is it *repeat 3x2 times*, or did you duplicate the original string or what?

Comment: The template shall return the CDATA string n x 2 times for i = 0 to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The template shall return the CDATA string n x 2 times for i = 0 to n.

Well, that's fairly trivial:

```
<xsl:template name="repeat">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="2 * $n > $i">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,'[i]')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', floor($i div 2), ']')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($string,'[i]')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template name="repeat">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > $i">
        <xsl:variable name="output">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,'[i]')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $i, ']')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($string,'[i]')"/>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($output, $output)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. In the example, the element `generate` will be replaced by the string `$n` number of times. I'm using DOE (`disable-output-escaping`) so the string is actual XML in the output. If it's supposed to be a string, just remove the DOE attribute.

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <generate/>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="n" select="3"/>
    <xsl:param name="baseString">
        <![CDATA[
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[i]</Data></Cell>
        ]]>
    </xsl:param>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="generate">
        <xsl:call-template name="copyXML">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$baseString"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copyXML">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
            concat(substring-before($string,'['),
            '[',$count,']',
            substring-after($string,']')))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test="$n - 1 > $count">
            <xsl:call-template name="copyXML">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count+1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

(Formatted after transform. Actual output would be on a single line because of the `normalize-space()`.)

```
<doc>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
        <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[0]</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
        <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[1]</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
        <Data ss:Type="String">WSCEAllergens[2]</Data>
    </Cell>
</doc>
```

Also note that the namespace prefix `ss` should be bound to a namespace in the output.

Comment: I'm using XSLT 1.0 and applying your code to an XML document containing only the data from my example works flawlessly. :-)

Comment: But I'm quite lost how to apply this to my project, because it shall only add certain elements with text inside certain elements and I haven't understood yet how to let your xslt know what to copy and where to put your xslt inside my xslt document.

Comment: I think, my question was not precise: The string I want to repeat is not part of the xml that the stylesheet has to transform, it's part of my xslt. So I'm looking for a template that I can hand this <Cell><DATA>Any String [i]</DATA></CELL> as parameter and get it back n times with i from 0 to n.

Comment: @FREDV - I think I just read the question wrong. I've updated my answer; hopefully it helps. Also note that you could use an extension in XSLT 1.0, like exslt, to treat the string as a node so you could do an apply-templates approach like my earlier answer.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot but I'm not finished with my problem yet and have edited my question.